# changing the values in many r variables

Tags: r

I want to do the equivalent of find and replace 1=0;2=0;3=0;4=1;5=2;6=3 for many different variables in my data set.

Things I've tried: 
making 1=0;2=0;3=0;4=1;5=2;6=3 into a function and using sapply. I changed the ; to , and changed the = to <- and no combination of these were recognized as a function. I tried creating a function with that definition and putting it into sapply and it didn't work. 
I tried using recode and it did not work:

```
wdata[ ,cols2] = recode(wdata[ ,cols2], 1=0;2=0;3=0;4=1;5=2;6=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a `data.frame` or `matrix` you can use direct indexing:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:6, 20, replace = T), ncol = 4));
df;
#V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  6  5  5  3
#2  4  1  1  3
#3  3  3  1  5
#4  2  3  3  6
#5  5  2  3  5

df[df == 1 | df == 2 | df == 3] <- 0;
df[df == 4] <- 1;
df[df == 5] <- 2;
df[df == 6] <- 3;
df;
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  3  2  2  0
#2  1  0  0  0
#3  0  0  0  2
#4  0  0  0  3
#5  2  0  0  2
```

Note that the order of the substitutions matters. For example, `df[df == 4] = 1; df[df == 1] <- 0;` will give a different output from `df[df == 1] <- 0; df[df == 4] <- 1;`

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was so helpful!

Comment: No worries @Ellis, glad to help.

Comment: Now do it when `1/2/3` goes to `4`, `4` goes to `1`, `5` to `2`, `6` to `3`. This only works if the new and old categories never overlap. It will be a case-by-case consideration - it is a fine answer for the current query.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, I completely agree with you. Already in this case, the order matters. I will edit the post to include a note.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using `recode` from `dplyr` with `sapply` or `mutate_all`:

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:6, 20, replace = T), ncol = 4));
df

library(dplyr)

f = function(x) recode(x, `1`=0, `2`=0, `3`=0, `4`=1, `5`=2, `6`=3)

sapply(df, f)

#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# [1,]  3  2  2  0
# [2,]  1  0  0  0
# [3,]  0  0  0  2
# [4,]  0  0  0  3
# [5,]  2  0  0  2

df %>% mutate_all(f)

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  3  2  2  0
# 2  1  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0  2
# 4  0  0  0  3
# 5  2  0  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

A looping alternative with `lapply` and `match` is as follows:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3)[match(x, 1:6)])
```

This uses a lookup table on the vector `c(0,0,0,1,2,3)` with `match` selecting the indices. Using the data.frame created by Maurits Evers, we get

```
dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  3  2  2  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  2
4  0  0  0  3
5  2  0  0  2
```

To do this for a subset of the columns, just select them on each side, like

```
dat[, cols2] <-
   lapply(dat[, cols2], function(x) c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3)[match(x, 1:6)])
```

or

```
dat[cols2] <- lapply(dat[cols2], function(x) c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3)[match(x, 1:6)])
```